# Code crashing compiler: main() returning a struct instead of an int

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, crash, compiler-errors

I'm experimenting with a piece of C code. Can anyone tell me why is VC 9.0 with SP1 crashing for me? Oh, and the code is meant to be an example used in a discussion why something like

```
 void main (void)
```

is evil.

```
struct foo { int i; double d; } main (double argc, struct foo argv)
{

    struct foo a;
    a.d=0;
    a.i=0;
    return a.i;
}
```

If I put

```
return a;
```

compiler doesn't crash.

Comment: The compiler shouldn't crash at all, it is a bug with the compiler if it crashes trying to understand your code.

Comment: +1 for the nasty example. Took me a bit to figure out what the frizzle you were doing :) Also, VS2010 C++ compiler now enforces main()'s signature (iow, the above code no longer compiles).

Comment: Try closing the struct with a semicolon.  See if that changes the behavior of the compiler.  It may indeed be a compiler bug.

Comment: As an aside, I'm impressed with VS2010 C++ compiler, as it better enforces the standard--including those pesky carriage returns at the end of header files!

Comment: Compilers shouldn't crash, even on invalid input.  Make sure to report the bug to the compiler vendor (Microsoft, in this case) when this happens.

Comment: The credits for struct idea should goto Clive Feather, who provided it in a review of The Annotated C Standard.

Comment: Oh, and what's the proper procedure to report this to M$?

Comment: @AndrejaKo:  You can file a defect report on http://connect.microsoft.com I can confirm that the internal compiler error occurs in Visual C++ 2010 as well, so your best bet is to report it for that version since it's more likely to be fixed then (if you don't want to report it, I can report it... either way.  If you do report the defect, be sure to post a link here so people can upvote it if they want).

Comment: Well, would it be too much trouble for you to report it? I never used connect before and don't have much experience with it.

Comment: I've reported the defect on Microsoft Connect:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565633

Comment: Confirmed crash here on VS2010 if you compile from command line as C code by using .c extension or by forcing C code by use of /TC command line option.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 compiles this successfully, but the program crashes with an access violation at `return a.i'`.

Comment: @DragonLord Thanks for the update. It's good to see that the code isn't causing compiler crashes any more.

Comment: ...and yes, the VS2010 compiler indeed returns error C1001 (`An internal error has occurred in the compiler`) trying to build this code.  The code does build with the VS2012 compiler.  This was tested using the respective command-line tools for both versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code gives undefined behavior. This doesn't require the compiler to crash, it just says you've basically broken the rules, so the compiler hasn't done anything wrong, no matter what happens.

Edit: that said, as a quality of implementation issue, it's absolutely true that there's basically never an excuse for the compiler to crash -- reasonably speaking, it should always exit normally, no matter what data you feed it.

Comment: Bad code should never crash a compiler. If the program itself crashes because of undefined behavior is a different story.

Comment: Maybe if the compiler crashed more frequently on such heinous constructs, we wouldn't see such horrid code in the wild. +100 for crash the hell out of anyone trying to compile the above.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere about a "hacker's" C compiler that would output nothing on success, but on *any* error would only output "No".

Comment: @dreamlax Errors should output nothing but return exit code 1, silly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you want to pose an esoteric question, then please construct a complete one.

How did you run the test?
What do you mean by crash?
What was your output?
Did you just compile, or compile and link, or compile and link and debug?
How is your compiler configured?
Where are you going with this experiment?

phrases like: "something like" "evil" are not informative enough to be useful

Follow UP:

Instinctively I'll guess that this crash is a consequence of a compiler
   optimization switch with which you permit the the compiler to make 
   certain assumptions that you are not conforming to.

my suppositions:

1- The void main(void) (without ;) is part of a comment you are making, but not
   part of the test you submitted.

2- Your program is incorrect, but this is deliberate in order to investigate
   the behaviour of the compiler/linker/execution environment.
   If this is indeed the case, you need to reduce the complexity of the test case.

Please simplify the test case to the bare minimum it takes to cause a crash.
I can't do it for you, I don't have the correct versions of software 
installed, anyway, it's your experiment.

will this crash?

```
   struct foo { int i; double d; };
   struct foo main( void)
       {
       int a=0;
       return a;
       }
```

or even this most minimal example?

```
   void * main(void)
   {
   return 0;
   }
```

of is it this (I doubt it):

```
   int main( double argc, char ** argv)
   {
   return 0;
   }
```

You get the idea. reduce the crash to it's essence. 
   Come up with a program that is error free except for the
   one thing that will make it crash.

Then report back.

Comment: Here' how to reproduce the problem: Start visual studio 2008 SP1 and make a new empty C++ project. Add a new source file and add .c extension by hand. This way it will be compiled as C. Press F7.
If you didn't change any settings, it will be build a debug build. Result: Microsoft optimizing compiler has stopped working. Event name: APPCRASH. Oh, and I read the question again. The evil and something like are informative enough. Their point of existence is to avoid comments like "C standard says int main (void) blah blah blah" because I already know that :) and also describes the use of the code

Comment: 1 nad 2 are correct. I guess I can't express myself in a good way sometimes. Your answer us now actually useful, so +1 and thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score -2):

put a semi colon between the end of your structure and main like so:

struct foo { int i; double d; }; main (double argc, struct foo argv)

you could also define a return type for main if your gonna return something:

struct foo { int i; double d; }; int main (double argc, struct foo argv)